# how to display text along link like Google

Tags: html, css, python-2.7, iframe

Actually i dont ve good words to express title. I am trying to print text along with links in the same as Google do while showing the results. For example:

[image]

I thought iframe would be best approach to do so but it does not.

code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages">List of programming</a>
<iframe src="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_programming_languages" style="border:none"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

Any one who knows?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to display title and content of the web-link in the same format as google does?

Comment: yes i want in the same way.

Comment: And where will the text and description come from?

Comment: from website. Like i ve tried to illustrate from pic

Comment: Well this is not as simple as you think.. you mind need to read about web scraping.